# Why PHP password_hash does use blowfish intstead threefish?

Tags: passwords, blowfish

I was wondering why PHP's hash_password function use blowfish instead of threefish. According to Bruce Schneier blowfish is outdated and He is recommending twofish or threefish. Is blowfish enough secure and threefish just slow the login authentication down?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PHP uses [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) for `password_hash()`, but since PHP is PHP, they have to maximize confusion, so they call it "Blowfish".

Besides being a family of [highly poisonous fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetraodontidae), Blowfish is a [block cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_(cipher)) for more than 20 years ago. Bcrypt is a password hashing function that happens to be derived from an internal block cipher which is similar to Blowfish -- but it is used for something completely different from what block cipher are meant to be used for, i.e. encryption.

[Threefish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threefish) is another block cipher, which was designed much later on for yet another purpose, which is the design of the [Skein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skein_(hash_function)) hash function. Now **pay attention**, for here comes the tricky point. "Hash functions" and "password hashing functions" are *completely different things*. Despite the similarity in name, they are very distinct beasts, that take different kinds of inputs, produce different kinds of outputs, and have very different security requirements and properties.

Threefish was designed as a block cipher for a variety of reasons, the primary of which being the need for large blocks (512 bits or more), because you need large blocks to make a hash function that resists collisions. However, collisions are completely irrelevant to password hashing, and the short block size of Blowfish (64 bits) is not a problem for bcrypt.

**As block ciphers**, Threefish is "better" than Blowfish in a lot of ways (bigger blocks, faster, can be implemented without tables...). As a building block for a hash function, Threefish is again better than Blowfish, but in different ways. As a building block for a password hashing function, Threefish is actually worse than Blowfish, for about the same reasons that Threefish is better than Blowfish for a hash function; in particular, Threefish can be implemented without tables. This means that Threefish allows for thoroughly optimized parallel implementations on [GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit), something which is good in general, and very bad for password hashing.

---

None of this really explains why PHP has not "switched to Threefish". This just tells why such a switch would be a bad idea.

Comment: You are too quick to blame PHP for the "naming confusion" here; the `CRYPT_BLOWFISH` constant takes its name from the library used, called [`crypt_blowfish`](http://www.openwall.com/crypt/). This is a reimplementation which originated in a password cracking tool of the "blowfish-based crypt() scheme" called `bcrypt`. It's not clear why it's named how it is, but it's certainly nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: The name that PHP uses inside of password_hash is bcrypt: http://php.net/password_hash so...

Answer (score 3):

PHP's [password_hash](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) uses the [bcrypt hashing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt). This is close to state-of-the-art for password storage with perhaps [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) lined up as its successor.

While you don't give a link for Schneier's (not corrected spelling) comment, I suspect that he was talking about the blowfish encryption algorithm. While bcrypt is based on blowfish, it is not considered to have similar weaknesses.

Comment: Agron2i will likely be the next successor to bcrypt, and is being worked on for 7.1

Comment: @ircmaxell, do you have a reference? I couldn't find one. And 7.1 what?

Comment: 7.1 would be the next minor version if PHP to be released. [Reference - mailing list thread](http://marc.info/?t=145249555900001&r=1&w=2)

Comment: Thx @ircmaxell.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `password_hash` is designed to be compatible with `crypt()`, which supports a limited range of hash algorithms. Of the supported algorithms, Blowfish is the only cryptographic algorithm:

- DES is known to be weak, and has a very short hash (2 character)
- Extended DES is little better
- MD5 is far too fast to use for password hashing - it is possible to make 100ks of trials per second on a modern PC
- SHA256 and SHA512 are both strong, but still faster than Blowfish, which is a bad thing for passwords. They do support a round count, which helps, and could theoretically be used

Any other function could easily be included in PHP, but would result in hashes that couldn't be verified using crypt.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how your answer is responding to the OP.